# Calling virtual function from member constructor

Tags: c++

I'm curious as to the behaviour of the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct A;
struct B {
    std::string b;
    B(A& a);
};
struct A {
    B member;
    virtual std::string f() { return "Hello, World!"; }
    A() : member(*this) {}
};
B::B(A& a) : b(a.f()) {}
int main() {
    std::cout << A().member.b;
}
```

Is this *required* to print the expected result? Or is it undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is legal. §12.7 [class.cdtor]/p4:

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it `x`) under construction or destruction,
>   the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.
>   If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of `x`
>   or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not `x` or one of
>   its base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

The UB case doesn't apply here.

Comment: I never get this right.. how come it doesn't apply? `a.f()` should refer to the complete object of x. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @MarcoA. UB only occurs if it refer to the complete object of `x` or one of that object's base class subobjects **but not `x` or one of its base class subobjects**. In this case, the relevant object under construction is an `A`, and the object expression refers to the object under construction, so the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out: `An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a complete object.`, so isn't `a` referring to a complete object here?

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes, `a` is a complete object, but there's no UB here because it's also `x` - i.e., the object currently under construction.

Comment: How can `A` be a complete object and an object under construction?

Comment: Also "UB only occurs if it refer to the complete object of `x` or one of that object's base class subobjects but not `x` or one of its base class subobjects." - That sounds the same to me...

Comment: @0x499602D2 "complete object" doesn't mean "object whose construction has finished". It means "an object that's not a subobject of any other object". See §1.8 [intro.object]/p2-3.